# Security Group not accepting in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to pass the SecurityGroup name as parameter in CloudFormation Template.While creating stack its providing me dropdown list of all security group and i am providing one but its failing with below error

"Parameter validation failed: parameter value launch-wizard-1 for parameter name SecurityGroup does not exist. Rollback requested by user."

```
{
    "Description": "Create an EC2 instance running the latest amazon Linux AMI.",
    "Parameters": {
        "KeyPair": {
            "Description": "The EC2 key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance",
            "Type": "String"
        },
          "SecurityGroup": {
             "Description": "Name of security group",
             "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::GroupName"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "EC2Instance": {
            "Properties": {
                "ImageId": "ami-0080e4c5bc078760e",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyPair"
                },
                "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "SecurityGroup"} ]
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance"
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "InstanceId": {
            "Description": "The InstanceId of newly created EC2 instance",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "EC2Instance"
            }
        }
    },
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your template (replacing the AMI and using my own Security Group name) and **it worked fine**.

It is possible that the instance is being launched in a **different VPC** to the Security Group.

Comment: You are correct i was using Security group present in different VPC.Thanks for pointing out.